What is optimal way to reverse video with html and javascript?
I'm building simple informative website for the browser. In this website I'm using video in the background the page look interesting. The problem is I wanted to video work in a certain sequence:

Video plays until the end
After video played it slows down in a half and played reverse until the 6th second of it
It loops between 6th second and end, and plays back and forth.

I can't find optimal way to do it.
I'm developing website on Next JS, but any abstract suggestion will work.

My first solution was to create 2 different videos, one for intro and second for loop, and seamlessly change them. But I couldn't a way to make transition invisible.
The second solution was to manipulate video with animation library GSAP, but video lagged a lot.
And third and currently the best attempt is to just change currentTime property in the video object itself inside of setInterval funciton

const playForward = () => {
    const video = videoRef.current!;
    if (loopIntervalRef.current) {
      clearInterval(loopIntervalRef.current);
    }

    //@ts-ignore
    loopIntervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (video.currentTime >= video.duration) {
        playBack();
      } else {
        video.currentTime += 0.04;
      }
    }, 120);
  };
 const playBack = () => {
    const video = videoRef.current!;
    if (loopIntervalRef.current) {
      clearInterval(loopIntervalRef.current);
    }

    //@ts-ignore
    loopIntervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (video.currentTime <= reversePoint) {
        playForward();
      } else {
        video.currentTime -= 0.04;
      }
    }, 120);
  };

It works almost perfectly, but video lagging sometimes while playing reverse.

The way video is encoded it's not great for reverse playing, this is because video uses key frames, subsequent frames require these key frames.   If your able to re-encode the video you could try reducing the key frame interval, this should help with reverse playing, but will increase the size of the file.  ps.  This is the reason why some video's scrub better than others, if someone encodes video to make as small as possible, they often don't scrub very well..

I think you should have two copies of the video, one normal and one reversed and to toggle between the two when they reach the end.
Luckily, the well known ffmpeg utility can create a copy in reverse using the following syntax...
ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/ffvid/frameCount.mp4 -vf reverse -af areverse reversed.mp4

As informed on this page.

Sorry for not commenting, as you proposed I used 2 copies of video, just reversed it with video editor.
